# Using $.ajax inside .click(function () {?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, onclick

This works:

```
$(function(){

    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://files.main.bloggerstop.net/uploads/3/0/2/5/3025338/snowstorm.js',
      async: false,
      dataType: "script",
    });

});
```

However this doesn't:

```
$("a#trigger").click(function(){

    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://files.main.bloggerstop.net/uploads/3/0/2/5/3025338/snowstorm.js',
      async: false,
      dataType: "script",
    });

});
```

This is a seasonal hack for a site (not mine), so it doesn't have to be perfect. Just need to be able to load an external .js file on click.

Thanks :).

Comment: use require.js http://requirejs.org/

Comment: how does it not work? what kind of errors are you getting? the code looks fine.

Comment: Is there a good reason why are you loading the script in a synchronous manner?

Comment: Maybe show us the html? The second version looks ok, the issue must be somewhere else.

Comment: There's no error . Simply put, nothing happens. As for synchronous loading, no reason. I didn't write the code and didn't think to remove it.

Comment: And you are sure you are targeting an anchor with an id of trigger?  Have you tried firebug?

Comment: Actually the first version should not work either (single origin policy). Do you have a live demo?

Comment: @Christophe What are you talking about? The `dataType` is "script"

Comment: @Christian You really should be specifying `error` just in case the request fails. In this case, that's not the problem at all, but it's something you probably want to include when using AJAX

Comment: @Ian dataType script or not, it's an ajax call.

Comment: @Christophe That's weird, I don't believe `google.com` and `jsfiddle.net` are the same domain. Yet: http://jsfiddle.net/qw5ge/

Comment: @Ian then maybe it switches to jsonp (or equivalent) automatically. Thanks for the demo!

Answer (score 3):

You removed the *"DOM ready"* code. Put it back in and it should work again.

```
$(function() {
    $("a#trigger").click(function(){

        $.ajax({
          url: 'http://files.main.bloggerstop.net/uploads/3/0/2/5/3025338/snowstorm.js',
          async: false,
          dataType: "script",
        });

    });
});
```

When you put your script at the top of the page, it runs immediately instead of waiting for the rest of the page to load.

By binding your handler in the DOM ready handler, it won't run until the document has loaded.

Also, make sure your selector matches your targeted element correctly.

Comment: Thanks. However, any variation of document.ready either inside head or body returns the same result. Nothing happens on click. :/

Comment: @Christian: Then your handler is not bound. Make sure you're not reusing the same ID on the page, and remove the `a` from the selector. It's not necessary since IDs must be unique.

Comment: Like this guy says. Without the $(function(){})/$(document).ready()/etc the events will be bound before the DOM elements have been generated, so will be bound to nothing. Also any id (#trigger) should be unique so you shouldn't need to specify what kind of element it is attached to (a). If you specifically don't want to use initialize you could use $(document).on('click', '#trigger', function(){}) which just watches the document rather than a specific element.

Comment: @Christian: Your event is firing, and you are getting the data back: http://i.imgur.com/dX7Or.png You're just not doing anything with it. Or rather.. it's not running.

Comment: Thank for that Mark. Forgive me for my naivety, but how would one "do" something with it? Literally just need that code dumped anywhere in the body tag.

Comment: @Christian I think you're thinking of `$.getScript` which automatically executes the retrieved code. You'll need to specify the `success` option for `$.ajax` and append the returned script to the DOM

Comment: New demo: http://www.christianbullock.com/so2.html

Almost there. I can append plain text in the "success", but can't append response.

Comment: @Ian what the OP is doing is equivalent to $.getScript http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Comment: @Christophe Yep, I missed the part in the `$.ajax` API docs that says "in 1.4 script will execute the script". The `getScript` page is more verbose about it

Answer (score 0):

I tried your demos and the issue is explained in the code itself:

> Initializes after body onload() by default (via addEventHandler()
>   call at bottom.)    To customize properties, edit below or override
>   configuration after this script    has run (**but before body.onload**),
>   eg. snowStorm.snowStick = false;

Your issue is that in the second scenario you load the script after the page has finished loading, so your script is never initialized.

[Update] I have set up a live demo. Compare:

- on DOM ready: http://jsfiddle.net/4gnxk/
- on load: http://jsfiddle.net/4gnxk/1/

The only difference between the two is the left side setting (`DOM ready vs. onload`)